# Address Book constants evaluating as zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I have a program where for certain code paths, the address book constants (such as kABPersonEmailProperty, kABPersonAddressProperty) evaluate to their normal non-zero value.  However, if I follow a different code path, all these constants evaluate to zero.

Furthermore, once I follow the "successful" code path, if I take the problematic code path it works.

Is this some kind of compile linkage issue ?

I could also be over-releasing a variable somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, mystery solved.  To Apple's credit, the behavior is documented.

See [link text](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html)

"Special Considerations: The value of these constants is undefined until one of the following has been called: ABAddressBookCreate, ABPersonCreate, ABGroupCreate."

Comment: Sure, it's documented. But I still think it's violating some language contract, because those variables are declared as `const`

Comment: I can't find the text on that page anymore. Problem still exists though.